# Ubuntu goes to Sleep when Power Plug is Connected

Tags: suspend, shutdown

I have Ubuntu 22.04, It was working well. Suddenly, Its screen went off. But I could see the indicator of hard disk is blinking. Then, I force shut it down by long pressing power key. And It refused to wake up for about 30 minutes. Then, it ran normally. Then again, it was working well and same thing happened. Instead of Shutting it down, I closed the lid, unplugged the cable and opened it after some time. And it woke up from sleep. Then, just when I try to insert the cable, immediately it goes to sleep. How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to disable auto-sleep:

There's an app called "Power", open it and change the value of the "Suspend when inactive for" to "Don't suspend"

Comment: Tried it. Then, it does not go to sleep. But, screen turns off immediately. And there is no way to turn it back on other than force shut down and power on after some time.

Comment: @BabanGain Are you sure it's not a hardware issue?

Comment: Well, it might be. I will diagnose it with the help of professional repairman